# google play store not working via squid ssl bump

Tags: proxy, squid

I have configured squid to not bump these domains:

```
.googleapis.com
.google.com
.gvt2.com
.googleusercontent.com
.youtube.com
.gstatic.com
youtubei.googleapis.com
accounts.google.com
```

squid.conf

```
acl do_not_bump dstdomain /usr/local/etc/squid/ssl.no-bump
ssl_bump splice do_not_bump
```

; however, in the squid logs, I see this:

```
==> /var/log/squid/cache.log <==
2023/01/15 00:00:01 kid1| ERROR: failure while accepting a TLS connection on conn464 local=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3127 remote=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:41393 FD 19 flags=1: 0x83377c180*1

==> /var/log/squid/access.log <==
1673811096.004     70 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx NONE_NONE/200 0 CONNECT play-fe.googleapis.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/142.250.65.238 -
```

Prior to making these changes, Google Play would immediately complain of a problem, but after I added those domains, it looks like it will work, but does not.  I am not seeing any other domains in the squid logs and am still thinking that I'm missing a domain.

Any ideas?

This also appears to break 2-factor authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
acl step1        at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump         peek step1

acl broken_sites ssl::server_name .google.com .googleapis.com .gvt2.com .googleusercontent.com .youtube.com .gstatic.com .google-analytics.com
ssl_bump splice localhost
ssl_bump splice broken_sites

ssl_bump         bump port_443
ssl_bump         bump all
```

I can add more domains to the list of "broken_sites" and squid will not intercept that traffic.